# How can I launch different workspaces with different sets of plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When using different workspaces for different SDKs, e.g. Appengine, Android & basic Java development, how can I make sure, only the required plugins are loaded when launching the desired workspace?

Comment: Actually if an Eclipse plugin is a good citizen, it will only load and eat up resources if it's required, e.g. when you clicked on an action belonging to that plugin. But if your main concern is all the different tools cluttering up your menus and toolbars, then going for the several different configurations suggested by @zvikico seems like a good way to go.

Comment: good to know, I always expected that the plugins are loaded upon eclipses launch.

Comment: You can actually disable some plugins from loading at startup. Under the preferences --> General --> Startup and Shutdown. Not all are listed, but those listed will not be loaded until needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to specify a different configuration folder. Use the `-configuration` argument when launching Eclipse.

By default, you get something like this:

```
eclipse/
   plugins/
   features/
   configuration/
```

By specifying a separate configuration folder, all those 4 folders will move to a new location. I usually use a folder called configs and add several numbered folders under it. So, I get something like:

```
eclipse/
   plugins/
   features/
   configs/
      c1/
         plugins/
         features/
         configuration/
      c2/
         plugins/
         features/
         configuration/
```

To do that, use the argument `-configuration configs/c1/configuration`. When running a given instance and installing plugins, they will be installed in the relevant location.

You can also add `-data` argument and specify the workspace folder location, or select it when Eclipse launches.

Comment: thank you zvikico for the great explanation of your solution!

Comment: Adding this note as an answer as I cannot comment on the accepted answer The `-configuration` option did work but I had to use the absolute path to the configuration folder (on OSX), maybe it's obvious but might help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think plugins are a function of your workspace. You'd probably need to have separate Eclipse installations. Or, there's a way to do a "shared" install, whereby the binary is in one place and the plugins are in another. That must mean that there's a startup parameter to tell it where to find plugins. Perhaps you could leverage that?