# How to bypass loading some plugins when eclipse starts up?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm coding with different languages (c, python, java, latex and ...)using eclipse on a MacBook(2gb ram, coredou 2.13). This needs to install many plugins for each language along with some other common plugins(mylyn, vrapper, svncontroller), which makes the machine very slow. Since every time I start eclipse, I aim to only use one language, then I really don't need many of the plugins to be loaded. I was thinking if there is any way to bypass loading unwanted plugins, then having a faster eclipse.

You may suggest to have separate eclipses for different languages, but this requires installing the same plugins for all eclipse copies separately, which is very tedious.

thanks for your help in advance

--
green-i

Comment: If you're using Eclipse 3.5 or 3.6 that are using p2 to manage the installation, it's no way to do it besides implementing a configurator to manage the installed bundles by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that some plugins won't be loaded when Eclipse starts. This can be done under the preferences, under General → Startup and Shutdown. Note that most plugins do not properly implement the required API, so they cannot be controlled in that way. Also, they will be loaded if activated, so make sure you close all views from the given plugin in your workspace, so it won't load (go over all the perspectives for that matter).

Another option is to create a single shared installation with multiple configurations. Each configuration will include plugins specific to a given task. For more details, read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692612/eclipse-how-can-i-launch-different-workspaces-with-different-sets-of-plugins).