# Start Eclipse just with the plugins you want

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use Eclipse IDE for all my project (PHP, Java, C, Python, Android). If I install them all in one edition it will take too long to start and I will have many buttons in my toolbar.  Now I have Eclipse edition for each language. I type `eclipse` when I want to work with Java, `eclipse-php` for PHP. Is there a way to have just one eclipse edition and let me do this?

Comment: I think the separate installs is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start Eclipse with the `-configuration` or `osgi.configuration.area` argument.

Form [The Eclipse runtime options help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html):

> osgi.configuration.area {-configuration}
>
> the configuration location
> for this run of the platform. The configuration determines what
> plug-ins will run as well as various other system settings. See the
> section on locations for more details.

A more detailed explanation how to use this feature is found here: [How can I launch different workspaces with different sets of plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692612/how-can-i-launch-different-workspaces-with-different-sets-of-plugins)